# Swiftmailer and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Having some problems implementing swiftmailer with the new symfony2 beta4, below is my code

```
$mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
$name = ucwords(str_replace('.',' ', $user->getScreenName()));
$email = 'me@me.com'; //$user->getEmail();
$message = $mailer::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('New Password')
        ->setFrom('Neokeo <blah@blah.com>')
        ->setTo("$name <$email>")
        ->setBody($this->renderView('MyBundle:User:reset.html.php', array('user',$user)));

$mailer->send($message);
```

and the error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mailer::newInstance() must implement interface Swift_Transport, none given
```

does anyone have any idea what i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$mailer` is an instance of the `Swift_Mailer` class (which is the class used for sending messages), but for creating a message, you need the `Swift_Message` class.

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
```

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-quickref

Comment: for namespace reasons there should be a \ in front of the Swift_Message. I swear i tried this before and it was giving a different error, but it worked this time. So thank you :)

Comment: @Ascherer Sorry, never touched Symfony before :).